# How to insert textbox value to Microsoft Access query?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, web-applications

I need to run a ms access query where the query will get value from the **text box**.

I have the following query for web application.

```
string sql = "SELECT [identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '*name*'";
```

where the **name** string should be coming from the **textbox**.

Can somebody advice me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your textbox is named as TextBox1.
In this case in C# the string will be:

```
string sql = "SELECT [identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '*" + TextBox1.Value + "*'";
```

Comment: I got this error with your recommendation "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type" 'string ' and 'string'

Comment: I am using asp.net and c# language

Comment: Thrown: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE LIKE '*w*''." (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException) Exception Message = "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE LIKE '*w*''.", Exception Type = "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException", Exception WinRT Data = ""

Comment: I think you wanted to say mate. Different things

Answer (score 0):

You use the ToString() method:

```
string sql = "SELECT [identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '*" + TextBox1.ToString() + "*'";
```